# How to filter ObservableCollection on multplie values

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, observablecollection, icollection

I have an observable collection.

The class of this collection has several fields which in turn can have server values.

I wish my user to be able to search on numerous fields and values.

I have got as far as using an ICollection but all the examples I have seen is based on searching on 1 field.

This is my class:

```
public class Tasks
{
    private string JobPriority;
    private string JobLabel;
    private string JobType;
    private string UserRef;
}

JobPriority can be 'High', 'Low'
JobLabel can be 'Apple', 'Android', 'Microsoft'
JobType can be  'Internal', 'Private', 'Public'
```

So, I instantiate my collection as such:

```
public ObservableCollection<KanbanModelExtra> Tasks
{
    get
    {
        if (_tasks == null)
        {
            TaskView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_tasks);
            TaskView.Filter = TaskFilter;
        }
        return _tasks;
    }
    set
    {
        _tasks = value;
    }
}
public ICollectionView TaskView { get; private set; }
```

and set my filter as such:

```
private bool TaskFilter(
    object item )
{
    var task = item as KanbanModelExtra;

    if ( task == null )
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ( var searchItem1 in JobPrioritiesToSearchOn )
    {
        if ( task.JobPriority == searchItem1 )
        {
            foreach ( var searchItem2 in JobLabelsToSearchOn )
            {
                if ( task.JobLabel == searchItem2)
                {
                    foreach (var searchItem3 in JobTypesToSearchOn)
                    {
                        if (task.JobType == searchItem3)
                        {
                            if ( SearchByCurrentUser )
                            {
                                if ( task.UserRef == HeartBeat.CurrentUser.UserRef )
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but this seems 'heavy' and ugly. Also, every change will refresh the collection. Where as I  would lie to fresh the collection after all criteria has been choosen.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

foreach madness can be replaced by this expression:

```
return ((SearchByCurrentUser && task.UserRef == HeartBeat.CurrentUser.UserRef) || !SearchByCurrentUser) &&
       JobPrioritiesToSearchOn.Contains(task.JobPriority) &&
       JobLabelsToSearchOn.Contains(task.JobLabel) &&
       JobTypesToSearchOn.Contains(task.JobType));
```

Comment: hmm, seems so simple!  Thanks for your answer. I shall put it in and report back. Thank you

Comment: Hi, i need to be away from my PC now :( i wish to do speed tests between both answers. I appreciate ur time and answer.replies and promise to get back as soon as I have completed this. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Chain the tests together.

```
var result = JobPrioritiesToSearchOn.Any(x => x == task.JobPriority);
result = result && JobLabelsToSearchOn.Any(x => x == task.JobLabel);
result = result && JobTypesToSearchOn.Any(x => x == task.JobType);

if (SearchByCurrentUser)
{
    result = result && task.UserRef == HeartBeat.CurrentUser.UserRef;
}

return result;
```

`Any()` will return true if any of the collection match the filter passed in. In plain English, the first line evaluates to true if any of the `JobPrioritiesToSearchOn` items are equal to `task.JobPriority`.

Comment: thanks i shall do a comparison between both these answers and respond back

Comment: @eocron I note that the original logic depends on `SearchByCurrentUser` - it can be false and yet a `true` result is still be the required output.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this too. Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi, i need to be away from my PC now :( i wish to do speed tests between both answers. I appreciate ur time and answer.replies and promise to get back as soon as I have completed this. Thanks again :)